# SSRS. Reports seem corrupted within the report viewer

Tags: wpf, winforms, ssrs-2012

I have a WPF application using server side SSRS reports. I'm using the WPF WinFormsHost control, embedding the winforms report viewer control, to display the reports.

On about 20 development pc's and client pc's everthing works ok. The problem is that in a new clients office, on 2 pc's only, the reports seem to be corrupted when viewing within the report viewer. (They print out fine)

Table data is ok, but header data field values are missing. Has anybody experienced this? I'm at a complete loss as to why on these 2 machines data seems to be missing in the report viewer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Winforms Report Viewer control is not designed to be embedded inside WPF application. You can use WindowsFormsHost Winforms control to host Report Viewer inside your WPF Application, but the data binding of the ReportViewer has to be handled programmatically, because the ReportViewer control will not have knowledge of WPF's Window datasource at all.

This is a sample walkthrough article of embedding Windows Forms control inside WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944.aspx

Comment: I am using the WPF WindowsFormHost  control. It works fine. Like I say, the issue is with 2 pc's only, in one office. There's no issue on the 20 or so other pcs it's running on. Thanks. (I've edited my original post to make it more clear)